# SSRS Multiple or single parameter choose (Reporting Service)

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS reporting service i create three parameter which are 
Category--"wonen"
Sub-Category-"Saree"
Color--"Red"

this three Parameter is like drop down list and all of the drop down use 
multiple vale and also Sub-Category parameter dependent on Category and Color Depend on Sub-Category. So can we use single drop down or all of the drop down list what ever user choose and use view report button?please kindly give some solution...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a little more complicated than you realize. You will want to have your 3 parameters - Category, SubCategory and Color. If the SubCat and Color are based on other parameters you'll need to create a separate dataset for each one so the proper SubCategories or Colors appear in the drop-down lists.

SubCat Dataset query example:

```
SELECT SUBCATEGORY FROM TABLE WHERE CATEGORY IN (@CATEGORY)
```

This will limit the subcategory list by the Category that was chosen in the Category drop-down.

For more info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3466/cascaded-parameters-in-sql-server-reporting-services/